# Trying out a test function for rectangle and coordinate classes to find area of the rectangle

Tags: python

I have 2 classes. "Rectangle" and "Coordinates" which find the difference between 2 co-ordinates tl (top left) and br (bottom right) and then use them to find the area of the rectangle.

```
class Rectangle: # rectangle class
    # make rectangle using top left and bottom right coordinates
    def __init__(self,tl,br):
        self.tl=tl
        self.br=br
        self.width=abs(tl.x-br.x)  # width
        self.height=abs(tl.y-br.y) # height
    def area(self):
        return self.width*self.height

class Coordinate: # coordinate class
     def __init__(self,x,y):
        # make coordinate obj with a reference (self), an x and a y
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
     def distance(self,another): # distance between 2 coordinates
        import math
        xdist=abs(self.x-another.x)
        ydist=abs(self.y-another.y)
        return math.sqrt(xdist**2+ydist**2)
```

So far I've written this as a test function to find out an area of a rectangle and it results in an AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'x'

```
def test_function():
    print("Testing Function")
    tl = Coordinate(3,10)
    br = Coordinate.distance(15,14)
    rect = Rectangle(tl,br)
    actual = rect.area()
    print("Expected Area is 12 * 4 = 48")
    print("Actual Result %d" % actual)
```

Is there anything I can change to the test_function code to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`def distance(self,another)`
You need to call this from one object, and pass another object as a parameter. Like

```
tl = Coordinate(3,10)
br = tl.distance(Coordinate(15,14))
```

Although, in your code, it looks like `tl` and `br` are supposed to be coordinates for the rectangle, so you should declare them as

```
tl = Coordinate(3,10)
br = Coordinate(15,14)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, adding that to the code gives me another error.
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'x'

Comment: Yeah, fixed that @Strewth